# UISlider slider stops sliding while implementing UITouch events

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I want to detect `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` events for `UISlider`.I created a custom `UISlider` class and added `UITouch` methods. Touch events worked fine but the slider stopped sliding. If i comment the touch methods it again starts sliding again. What have i missed ? Or how i can make both sliding and touch events work ?
My actual problem is ,i am trying to change the size of thumbnail image when user presses the slider thumbnail image.Moving a slider returns some value,but i want to change when the slider value remains same for long time.Here's a little code what i am trying is

```
 cSlider=[[CLSlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,90,480,40)];



 [cSlider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderL.png"
                                                      ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  [cSlider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderR.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];


 [cSlider setThumbImage:[self imageByDrawingCOnImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"]:sColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  [cSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

i am trying to change the thumbnail image on long press of slider at particular place.Again the problem is the UITouch Events or UIGesture triggers for whole UISlider not from the place where currently Thumbnail is..

Comment: can you show some code of your touch event methods.

Comment: I am just adding empty touch events methods...

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible you can download a zip from [here](https://github.com/AalokParikh/pinch-and-uiguesture)
this shows how to do it. it is not my created demo but found on some site this will shows you how to handel two gesture events simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

You can use "value Changed" event instead of touch began and touch moved events.

Comment: I want to use timer to detect how long user has pressed and not moved and accordingly firing some events.UIGesture(suggested in Aaloks sample) is working fine along with sliding but don't know why touch events not working.

Comment: Can you show some code?, BTW you can implement the same "timer to detect how long user has pressed" with value Changed event also.